# using relations with CGridView

Tags: yii

I'll describe the problom as clearly as I can.

I have activeDataProvider:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Menu', array(
    'criteria'=>array(         
       'with' => array('roles'),
    ),
));
```

then I'am using CGridView with checkbox:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'menu-grid',
    'selectableRows' => 2,
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
                   'id',
                   'title',
                   array(
                       'class'    => 'SCheckboxColumn',
                       'header'   => 'View',
                       'name'     => 'Roles[Actions][can_view]',
                       'id'       => 'roles_action_can_view',
                       'value'    => '$data->id',
                       'checkBoxHtmlOptions' =>
                                      array('checked' => $data->roles->can_view),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Then in Menu Model relations:

```
return array(
        'roles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Rolesmenus', 'menu_id'),
    );
```

and in Rolesmenus Model relations:

```
return array(
        'menu' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Menu', 'menu_id'),
    );
```

So, I cant access $data->roles->can_view variable, when I var_dump all $data object I can see these attributes in _attributtes private array but I cant them access through CGridView.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

array('checked' => $data->roles->can_view,),

needs to be
array('checked' => '$data->roles->can_view',),

Answer (score 0):

When your relation is a HAS_MANY then calling that relation will return an array of that ActiveRecord.  The CGridView won't display an array, so what I have done in the past is write a function in the model that contains the relation to take all the values in the array and create a string from them.  For example with your example in the menu model do something like this

```
public function rolesToString()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    if($roles) {
        $string = '';
        foreach($roles as $role) {
            $string .= $role->can_view . ', ';
        }
        return substr($string,0,strlen($string)-1); // substr to remove trailing comma
    }
    return null;
}
```

then the 'value' attribute of the CGridView for that column should look like this

```
'value'=>'$data->rolesToString()'
```

There is some more information about using HAS_MANY, with, and CGridView [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8180-cactivedataprovider-and-cgridview-relation-field-and-condition-join-bug/)

Answer (score -1):

the best way to clean out the last comma is..
trim(',',string)
regards